# In Prisma how do I fetch data as RDBMS join tables resultset in tabular format instead of nested?

Tags: prisma, plumatic-schema

I want to display data in tabular format of two tables. In Prisma I am getting a nested data (Eager). How do I get data in alongside?

Let's say I have user and post tables. I might make mistake in terminology so I am writing in plain SQL.

```sql
select user.id, user.full_name, post.title, post.publishedAt from user JOIN post ON (user.id = post.user_id);
```

| id | full_name | title | publishedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Prashant | ORM | 01-01-2023 |
| 1 | Prashant | NUXT | 02-01-2023 |

```js
const user = await prisma.user.findMany({
  select: {
    full_name: true,
    id:true
    post: {
      select: {
        title: true,
        publishedAt:true
      },
    },
  },
})
```